# Python character count beside each line of a file

Tags: python, url-rewriting, counter, readfile

Problem: I must take the below text as a file named data.txt and add in a letter counter which only counts the letters A-Z and a-z left justified of the center justified text. done with lettercounter.ljust(width) and text.cjust(width)

This program must take the user input of a file name, and return the output file as this program does. This works, my only issue is how to go about doing this counter.

The data.txt file I open reads like:

```
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
       Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
    All mimsy were the borogoves,
       And the mome raths outgrabe.
                            - Lewis Carroll
```

I need it to read the letter characters at the left justificiation like:

```
28:
25:
24:
23:
12:
```

There is more to this code, but only for statistical data I have working. I didn't want to waste peoples time with code that isn't in question.

What I have:

```
def main():

    fileName = input("Enter name of input file:   ")
    infile = open(fileName, "r")
    infileData = infile.read()
    outfileName = fileName.split(".")#Should split the file name from the format
    outfileName = outfileName[0] + ".out"
    outfile = open(outfileName, "w")
    outfile.writelines(infileData)

    print("The name of output file is:",outfileName)
    print()
```

What I need to be fixed. Any help would be great.

```
with (infileData, 'r') as line:
    for line in range(line):
        line.count(len(line.split()))
        outfile.writelines(infileData)

main()
```

My theory is to create a loop, and return each line count to the left justified counters. My problem is that I have no clue on how to do this.

I do not know how many lines the user's files will actually be using, but it will be located within the same directory as the program. So I do not need to search the computers directory or have the user input the directory file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a oneliner that does what you seem to be looking for. `strings.ascii_letters` contains a concatenation of a-zA-Z, but you can choose a different character set if you so require.

Integrating this function in your existing code should not be too difficult now. Here's some code showing that it adheres to the numbers you suggested.

```
import string

def count_letters(line):
    return sum(line.count(x) for x in string.ascii_letters)

jabberwocky = [
"'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves        ",
"       Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;    ",
"    All mimsy were the borogoves,          ",
"       And the mome raths outgrabe.        ",
"                            - Lewis Carroll"]

for line in jabberwocky:
    print(count_letters(line))
```

Outputs:

```
28
25
24
23
12
```

Comment: I thank you for the code you have given me, it worked well for my needs... Once I figured out how to get it to do what I wanted it to. If you are wondering how to convert the code to what I needed, read below.

for line in open(fileName):
  line
  lettercounttop = sum(line.count(x) for x in string.ascii_letters)
  
  print(lettercounttop, line)

Output

28 'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves

25        Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;

24     All mimsy were the borogoves,

23        And the mome raths outgrabe.

12                             - Lewis Carroll

I still need the :